# PL/PGSQL - Cannot assign array_agg from SELECT statement to variable

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, plpgsql

I need to fetch all the children area ids given a certain area id. In the table `areas`, there's a `parent_id` field that references the `areas` table itself. Now there can be more than multiple levels for example area with id `1` can be a parent of area with id `2` and area with id `2` can be a parent of area with id `3` and so on. So when I call this function I need all the descendants of a certain area id.

```
SELECT id, get_all_children(id) as children from areas where id = 1;
```

The result should be

```
| id       | children       |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1        | {2,3}          |
```

Here is what I have tried so far

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_all_children(ancestors INT[])
RETURNS INT[]
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
    childrenRet INT[];
BEGIN
    SELECT
        ARRAY_AGG(id::INT) INTO childrenRet
    FROM areas
    WHERE parent_id = ANY(ancestors);

    IF childrenRet = '{}' THEN
        RETURN childrenRet;
    END IF;
    RETURN ARRAY_CAT(get_all_children(childrenRet), childrenRet);
    
END;
$$;
SELECT id, get_all_children(id) as children from areas where id = 492;
```

But the result I get is

```
| id       | children       |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 492      | {3044}         |
```

I tried returning the direct children as

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_all_children(ancestors INT[])
RETURNS INT[]
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
    childrenRet INT[];
BEGIN
    SELECT
        ARRAY_AGG(id::INT) INTO childrenRet
    FROM areas
    WHERE parent_id = ANY(ancestors);

    RETURN childrenRet;
    
END;
$$;
SELECT id, get_all_children(id) as children from areas where id = 492;
```

I still get the same result.

Now I tried

```sql
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(id) FROM areas WHERE parent_id = 492;
```

This is the result I get

```
                                    array_agg
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{3044,3075,923,1470,774,1466,1473,1468,1467,3043,1471,1469,922,1472,3076,1474,920}
```

I'm guessing the problem is here but I can't figure out how to deal with it.

```sql
SELECT
    ARRAY_AGG(id::INT) INTO childrenRet
FROM areas
WHERE parent_id = ANY(ancestors);
```

Comment: Your title seems misleading. You seem to be assigning to that variable perfectly fine, i.e. no errors. Your problem is with the result your function is returning, so rename your question to reflect that.

Comment: If the assignment was correct, I should be getting an array of all the direct children, instead I'm only getting the first element.

Comment: I've updated the answer with an adjustment to your procedure and the result, plus a fiddle link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply postpone the `array_agg` operation to the last query expression, after having found all the children recursively, like this:

[The fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ddabd555057935bf51ecd770ca381402)

```
-- Aggregate all of the recursively found descendants
WITH RECURSIVE cte01 (children, lev) AS (
        SELECT a1.id, 0 FROM areas AS a1 WHERE a1.parent_id = 1 UNION ALL
        SELECT a1.id, lev+1
          FROM areas AS a1
          JOIN cte01 AS c1
            ON a1.parent_id = c1.children
     )
SELECT array_agg(children ORDER BY lev, children) AS children FROM cte01
;
```

The result:

| children |
| --- |
| {2,3,492,774,920,922,923,1466,1467,1468,1469,1470,1471,1472,1473,1474,3043,3044,3075,3076} |

We can do the same thing in the form of a function as well:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_all_children(start_id int)
RETURNS INT[]
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
    childrenRet INT[];
BEGIN

WITH RECURSIVE cte01 (children, lev) AS (
        SELECT a1.id, 0 FROM areas AS a1 WHERE a1.parent_id = start_id UNION ALL
        SELECT a1.id, lev+1
          FROM areas AS a1
          JOIN cte01 AS c1
            ON a1.parent_id = c1.children
     )
SELECT array_agg(children ORDER BY lev, children) AS children INTO childrenRet FROM cte01
;
    RETURN childrenRet;
    
END;
$$;
```

[Updated fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ddabd555057935bf51ecd770ca381402)

Example:

```
SELECT get_all_children(1) as children;
```

The result:

| children |
| --- |
| {2,3,492,774,920,922,923,1466,1467,1468,1469,1470,1471,1472,1473,1474,3043,3044,3075,3076} |

Comment: I had both approaches in mind, but couldn't think that combining both of them would give me what I want. Thank you for bringing it up.